# Reproducing audio selected with jfilechooser in netbeans

Tags: audio, netbeans, jfilechooser

Ok, here's the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import sun.audio.*;

    public class Sound {
        public static void main ( String Args[]){        
             JFileChooser openf =new JFileChooser();
             openf.showOpenDialog(null);
             File fl= openf.getSelectedFile();   
             String sound = fl.getAbsolutePath();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sound);
             InputStream in;
             try{            
                 in = new FileInputStream(sound);
                 AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
                 AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
             }catch(Exception e){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());  
             }
        }    
    }
```

Im working this application to allow the selection of audio files (through the jfilechooser) such as: mp3, wma or wav for its reproduction.
The exception I keep having is the following: 'java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream'.

I heard somewhere else that some of the sun.audio classes im importing were having some problems. Could that be?

Thanks. 
Miguel André.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to play an mp3 file. Java doesnt support mp3 natively. Your code is capable of playing wave(*.wav) files only. JavaFX supports mp3 out-of-the-box. Java supports MP3 with use of an external plug-in([JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html),[FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/),[JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) ..)